# sorting text file alphabetically in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, text, alphabetical-sort

I am trying to code a program in C# that sort a text file containing familyname followed by comma and followed by first name. How can I sor he text file alphabetically based n family name.

Comment: where is code? give some code here which help to answer your problem.

Comment: it is my first time codding with C# I have no idea how to do it I need to do it from scrach here is some example :

Comment: namespace cse1302_Lecture18_FileIO_Prez
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("NameInput.txt");  //if file in bin/debug

            char[] delims = {','};

            //string[] names = {"",""};

            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string data_line = sr.ReadLine();
                //names = data_line.Split(delims);
                Console.WriteLine(data_line);

            }
            sr.Close();

Comment: code is not in comment. edit your question and put there.

Comment: No need to write a program for this. Use the existing `sort` program.

Answer (score 10):

There are lots of options, depending upon the details.  Untested, but something like this should be close.

```
string inFile = @"C:\someInFile.txt";
string outFile = @"C:\someOutFile.txt";
var contents = File.ReadAllLines(inFile);
Array.Sort(contents);
File.WriteAllLines(outFile, contents)
```

Comment: Upvoted, Here two text files have been used, Could have used the same file to write the output too.

Answer (score 0):

This is VB.NET, but the translation should be easy:

```
Public Sub FileCreateReadAndSort()
    'Read data from database and write to unsorted text file
    Dim dv As DataView = DataLib.QryToData("select  * from gen where rn<10", EnumLib.DBList.Gen, EnumLib.DataObj.DataView)
    Dim S As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To dv.Count - 1
        With dv(i)
            S = S & RTrim(.Item("surname")) & ", " & RTrim(.Item("name")) & vbCrLf
        End With
    Next
    Dim SW As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\fileOriginal.txt")
    SW.Write(S)
    SW.Flush()
    SW.Close()
    SW.Dispose()

    'read in unsorted text file
    Dim SR As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("c:\temp\fileOriginal.txt")
    Dim S2 As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Do While Not SR.EndOfStream
        S2.Add(SR.ReadLine)
    Loop

    'sort file lines and write to sorted file
    Dim S3 As Array = S2.ToArray
    Array.Sort(S3)

    Dim SW2 As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\fileSorted.txt")
    For i As Integer = 0 To S3.Length - 1
        SW2.Write(S3(i) & vbCrLf)
    Next i
    SW2.Flush()
    SW2.Close()
    SW2.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You could use this,

```
FileStream readerStream = new FileStream(@"Desktop\Source\text.txt", FileMode.Open);
string[] content = null;

//Read the content
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readerStream))
{
   content = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   //Remove the entries in the file
   readerStream.SetLength(0);
}

FileStream writerStream = new FileStream(@"Desktop\Source\text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writerStream))
{
   //Sort the content and write back to the same file
   Array.Sort(content);
   writer.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, content));
}
```